# can't get file content for url when grab latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I want to convert given postcode to latitude and longitude to integrate in my cart project.
But when I try to grab latitude and longitude with google api they are showing some error like,

> "We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now."

What is wrong with my code? My code is shown below.

```
function getLatLong($code){
 $mapsApiKey = 'AIzaSyC1Ky_5LFNl2zq_Ot2Qgf1VJJTgybluYKo';
 $query = "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/geo?q=".urlencode($code)."&output=json&key=".$mapsApiKey;
 //---------

 // create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);


 //-----------
 //$data = file_get_contents($query);
 // if data returned
 if($data){
  // convert into readable format
  $data = json_decode($data);
  $long = $data->Placemark[0]->Point->coordinates[0];
  $lat = $data->Placemark[0]->Point->coordinates[1];
  return array('Latitude'=>$lat,'Longitude'=>$long);
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}


print_r(getLatLong('SW1W 9TQ'));
```

Comment: Think about what this error message is telling you, and why they'd do that. Either your code is wrong or you are (as the message says) sending too many requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use useragent

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0');
```

Also check whether you missed or not to send any HTTP Request header. Also check whether you are using required parameters(GET or POST) with your request.

By the way, If you are using too many requests then you have nothing to do with this error. Just stop sending requests, or limit your requests so that it doesn't upset the server.